# Swift ViewModel properties can't access in ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mvvm, viewmodel

In Swift project contains,

**CartViewModel.swift**

```
@objc public class CartViewModel: NSObject {

    let apiService: APIService

    var alertMessage: String? {
        didSet {
            self.showAlertClosure?()
        }
    }
    var isShow: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.updateStatus?()
        }
    }
    @objc public var dataCount: Int {
        return models.count
    }
}
```

**ListViewController.h**

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@class CartViewModel;

@interface ListViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) CartViewModel *viewModel;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**ListViewController.m**

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.viewModel.dataCount);
```

// Accessing any property gives this error

> Property 'dataCount' cannot be found in forward class object 'CartViewModel'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to access properties of a class inside the implementation file of an Objective-C class, you need to import the header of the class. Simply forward declaring the class by doing `@class YourClass` only makes the type itself visible, but it doesn't expose its properties/methods.

Since Swift files don't have headers, you need to import the Swift header of your module.

So in your `ListViewController.m` do

`#import <YourModule/YourModule-Swift.h>`

Answer (score 1):

In your Objective-C implementation you need to import the Xcode-generated header file for Swift.  Add this to your imports replacing `ProductModuleName` with your target's name:

`#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes here with this problem; used `@class` and imported the Swift header but the problem is not solved yet... Double check you have made your Swift class `public` and not `internal`